# Проблема с определением конструкции языка

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно начала учиться делать игры на Unity. В обучающем уроке учитель создал скрипт Input и скрипт Gun. В Input он написал строку

```
[SerializeField] private Gun _shotGun;
```

И затем вызывал метод из Gun через _shotGun. Я понимаю, для чего это, но не понимаю, чем является _shotGun? Написано, что полем. Я думала - экземпляром класса...

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, ознакомиться с данным уроком и указанными в нём кодом?

Comment: _shutGun - это переменная (поле, свойство) некого класса, которая имеет тип Gun, она приватная (то есть к ней можно получать доступ только с объекта. А также оно помечено атрибутом, что оно сериализируемое.

Comment: у Романа Сакутина урок смотрела

Comment: @Helena не стоит обращать внимание на инфоцыган, лучше подучите основы C# на метаните или на ютубе codeblog.. еще есть андрей широкорядов, там SOLID и паттерны хорошо объясняются на примерах. На SO есть еще вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: основы, вроде бы, подучила уже) вот, в Unity пытаюсь это проецировать

Comment: @Helena не думаю, что сакутин/дударь/хаудихо поможет вам в изучении юнити, есть оф. документация с примерами, но там на английском, но никто не мешает использовать гугл переводчик. но это конечно всё моё субъективное мнение слушать которое не стоит ведь я не изучал юнити

Comment: @Aarnihauta да по Unity видеогайдов только ленивые не снимали. Типа "пилить игры - это суперпросто, каждый школьник справится, вот смотрите", они как бы занижают сильно порог вхождения в отрасль, но накапливают технический долг, когда новичек набыдлокодил, оно как-то работает, а что делать дальше - непонятно, потому что код в таком ужасном состоянии, что дорабатывать его просто нереально. И больше половины из таких новичков просто бросают это дурное занятие, потому что "непонятно, что дальше делать, сложна". Это и есть цена положенного болта на SOLID и ООП как на никому ненужную нудятину.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам немного надо подучить основы C# и ООП.

```
//    название класса
class MyClass
{
    // приватное поле типа 'int'
    private int _myField;

    // какой-то публичный метод
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Класс - это некий шаблон для создания объекта. Созданный объект из какого-то класса еще назвают экземпляром этого класса. Переменная или поле может содержать ссылку на этот экземпляр. Класс - ссылочный тип данных.

```
// создание экземпляра, переменная instance - экземпляр класса MyClass
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyMethod(); // вызов публичного метода для данного экземпляра класса
```

```
// класс, наследующий базовый класс MonoBehavior
class MyController : MonoBehavior
{
    // приватное поле типа 'MyClass'
    private MyClass _instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        _instance = new MyClass();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _instance.MyMethod(); // то же самое, вызов метода для экземпляра MyClass
    }
}
```

В вашем случае экзепляр `new MyClass()` создается в недрах Unity. Но суть работы уже с созданным экземпляром как в Unity, так и в чистом C# одна и та же.

Чтобы подробнее понять, как оно работает, изучите принципы ООП - инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм. Они для всех языков программирования и всех фреймворков одни и те же.

Атрибут `[SerializeField]` в данном случае к вопросу ООП не относится, он выполняет другие задачи, не обращайте на него много внимания.

Comment: Да я вроде знаю, что это. Просто конкретно в этом случае не поняла, чем является содержимое строки. Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: @Helena если всё понятно, то вы можете выбрать и принять наиболее полезный ответ галочкой.

Comment: еще один вопросик: использование такой конструкции оправдано или все таки не совсем корректно?

Comment: @Helena какой именно? Переменная может существовать только внутри метода. Если нужно что-то хранить в объекте - без полей вам никак не обойтись.

Comment: я по примеру делаю. у меня есть такая строка: 
[SerializeField] private LaserGun _laserGun;
но мне нечего на _lasergun повесить. у меня только два Transform gunpositon есть. с помощью _laserGun я получаю в Input доступ к методу Fire.
_laserGun.Fire(); 
вся проблема в том, что не знаю, что на laserGun повесить. может, есть какой то другой способ обратиться к методу

Comment: @Helena если у вас появился новый вопрос, вы можете его задать отдельно. Подозреваю, что вы хотите понять, что такое "наследование", типа когда есть "пушка" и у нее есть наследники "дробан", "рельса", "пулемет Максим", и метод "Стрелять()" идет именно от "пушки". Поле в классе должно быть типа родителя, тогда в него можно будет положить, то есть присвоить любого наследника.

Comment: @Aarnihauta не надо никакой рефлексии новичкам. Тем более, оно в Unity вообще опасно, потому что будет тормозить всё. Mono - это не Core CLR, там нативная компиляция, и рефлексия там - очень дорого. Лучше проектировать объектную модель правильно, а не втыкать костыли. Рефлексия - в основном как раз для костылей. В данном случае достаточно метод сделать публичным `public`, что я и показал в ответе.

Comment: @aepot понял, зря я свою копейку вставил в тему, в которой ни разу не бывал. удалю коммент про рефлексию

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializeField] 
private Gun _shotGun;
```

`_shotGun` - это одновременно и то и другое:

- это переменная, хранящая ссылку на экземпляр класса `Gun` (но нам не показали, где его инстанциируют и присваивают ссылку в эту переменную)
- это приватное поле какого-то класса, который нам опять же не показали

```
class SomeClass
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Gun _shotGun;

    ...
}
```